CSS: How to adjust element's line height to match surrounding text?
I'm developing a website using Pretendard as the default font. This font works well because it has balanced top and bottom padding. However, I need to use a different font for emphasis in certain places. The problem is that this other font has unbalanced height, particularly with excessive bottom padding.

How can I remove or adjust the top and bottom padding of the span.status-stop element to match the height of the surrounding text?

I guess "Khmer" actually supports Khmer scripts and you need support for this writing system? Khmer fonts usually have quite large descenders (compared to "latin/western" fonts). If you need multi language support I highly recommend to search for a font family covering all required writing systems as mixing different fonts can introduce way more of these inconsistencies. Otherwise you may mitigate this effect by applying CSS descent-override

Are you saying that you will always be using only uppercase?

You are looking for text-box-trim and text-box-edge but they are new features that you cannot use in production for now. Related: https://css-tricks.com/two-css-properties-for-trimming-text-box-whitespace/
